# pbkdf2 implementation not validating

Tags: php, hash

I have these functions:

```
// Compares two strings $a and $b in length-constant time.
    function a_pbkdf2_slow_equals($a, $b)
    {
        $diff = strlen($a) ^ strlen($b);
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($a) && $i < strlen($b); $i++) {
            $diff |= ord($a[$i]) ^ ord($b[$i]);
        }

        return $diff === 0;
    }

    function a_pbkdf2_validate_password($password, $correct_hash)
    {
        $params = explode(':', $correct_hash);
        if (count($params) < HASH_SECTIONS) {
            if (strlen($correct_hash) == 32 && count($params) == 1) {
                return md5($password) == $correct_hash;
            }
            return false;
        }
        $pbkdf2 = base64_decode($params[HASH_PBKDF2_INDEX]);
        return $this->a_pbkdf2_slow_equals(
            $pbkdf2,
             $this->a_pbkdf2_apply(
                $params[HASH_ALGORITHM_INDEX],
                $password,
                $params[HASH_SALT_INDEX],
                (int) $params[HASH_ITERATION_INDEX],
                strlen($pbkdf2),
                true
            )
        );
    }

  function a_pbkdf2_apply($algorithm, $password, $salt, $count, $key_length, $raw_output = false) {
        $algorithm = strtolower($algorithm);
        if(!in_array($algorithm, hash_algos(), true))
            die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid hash algorithm.');
        if($count <= 0 || $key_length <= 0)
            die('PBKDF2 ERROR: Invalid parameters.');
        $hash_length = strlen(hash($algorithm, '', true));
        $block_count = ceil($key_length / $hash_length);
        $output = '';
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $block_count; $i++) {
            // $i encoded as 4 bytes, big endian.
            $last = $salt . pack('N', $i);
            // first iteration
            $last = $xorsum = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true);

            // perform the other $count - 1 iterations
            for ($j = 1; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $xorsum ^= ($last = hash_hmac($algorithm, $last, $password, true));
            }
            $output .= $xorsum;
        }
        if($raw_output)
            return substr($output, 0, $key_length);
        else
            return bin2hex(substr($output, 0, $key_length));
    }

    // call this to create new password
    function a_pbkdf2_create_hash($password)
    {
        // format: algorithm:iterations:salt:hash
        if(function_exists('random_bytes')){ //IF > PHP 7.2
                    $salt = base64_encode(random_bytes(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE));
            } else {
                    $salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(PBKDF2_SALT_BYTE_SIZE, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
        }
        return PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM.':'. PBKDF2_ITERATIONS.':'.$salt.':'.
            base64_encode($this->a_pbkdf2_apply(
            PBKDF2_HASH_ALGORITHM,
            $password,
            $salt,
            PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
            PBKDF2_HASH_BYTE_SIZE,
            true
        ));
    }
```

Generating the password hash/etc `a_pbkdf2_create_hash()` seems to be fine, however, when I validate the string against the stored hash using `a_pbkdf2_validate_password()`, it returns `false`

Not sure what's up. As PHP7.2 has removed `mcrypt_create_iv`, I had to use the `random_bytes` as an alternative.

Comment: Is there some reason to not use PHP standard `hash_pbkdf2` and a if?

Comment: even **hash_pbkdf2** does not work, still get false..... Think I'll scrap this way and just try **password_hash()**